# Replace string ${stringKey} on file before war task on gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I 've a multi-project gradle configuration. So I've got a `build.gradle` for each subproject and another one where I define general tasks.

Basicly, in the general `build.gradle` file I set out performing environtments, each one for `production`, `pre-production`, `development`, and so on purposes.

I set several containers defining a class:

```
class RemoteContainer {
    String name
    String container
    String hostname
    Integer port
    String username
    String password
    String purpose
}
```

So, I set the purpose of the container setting `purpose` field to `'production'`, `'pre-production'` or `'development'`.

Then, I'm able to create several containers:

```
def developmentRemoteContainers = [
    new RemoteContainer(
        name: 'wildfly8',
        container: 'wildfly8x',
        hostname: '----',
        port: ----,
        username: '----',
        password: '----'
        purpose: 'development'
    ),
    new RemoteContainer(
        name: 'glassfish4',
        container: 'glassfish4x',
        hostname: '----',
        port: ----,
        username: '----',
        password: '----'
        purpose: 'development'
    )
]

def preproductionRemoteContainers = [
    new RemoteContainer(
        name: 'wildfly8',
        container: 'wildfly8x',
        hostname: '----',
        port: ----,
        username: '----',
        password: '----'
        purpose: 'pro-production'
    ),
    new RemoteContainer(
        name: 'glassfish4',
        container: 'glassfish4x',
        hostname: '----',
        port: ----,
        username: '----',
        password: '----'
        purpose: 'pre-production'
    )
]

def productionUserRemoteContainers = [
    new RemoteContainer(
        name: 'wildfly8',
        container: 'wildfly8x',
        hostname: '---',
        port: ----,
        username: '----',
        password: '----'
        purpose: 'production'
    ),
    new RemoteContainer(
        name: 'glassfish4',
        container: 'glassfish4x',
        hostname: '----',
        port: ----,
        username: '----',
        password: '----'
        purpose: 'production'
    )
]
```

After that, I create tasks according the content of each remote container:

Example tasks:

```
remoteContainers.each { config ->
    task "deployRemote${config.name.capitalize()}"(type: com.bmuschko.gradle.cargo.tasks.remote.CargoDeployRemote) {
        description = "Deploys WAR to remote Web Application Server: '${config.name}'."
        containerId = config.container
        hostname = config.hostname
        port = config.port
        username = config.username
        password = config.password
        dependsOn war
    }

    task "undeployRemote${config.name.capitalize()}"(type: com.bmuschko.gradle.cargo.tasks.remote.CargoUndeployRemote) {
        description = "Deploys WAR to remote Web Application Server: '${config.name}'."
        containerId = config.container
        hostname = config.hostname
        port = config.port
        username = config.username
        password = config.password
    }
}
```

So, it's the way how I'm creating my deploy and undeploy tasks for each container and performing context.

As you're able to figure out each task depends of the war task. So, my projects have a file containing a string like `${stringKey}` which I need to replace it according of each container purpose.

So, `${stringKey}` must be replaced by `config.purpose`.

**EDIT**

There are basicly two files:

- Under `/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`: This file contains database server location information. According to the server environtment, the database location is at an IP/PORT/DATABASE... For example:

  `<property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="${ip}"/>
  <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.port" value="${port}"/>`
- Under `/src/main/resources/configuration.settings.environtment`: This file contains only this line `scope = ${scope}`.

The replacement must be made at `war` generation.

I've absolutly no idea how to do that.
Any ideas?

Comment: What you're asking is not really clear. You want to open a file and replace a string in it? Why? What is the filename? At what point of the lifecycle must this happen? How are you adding your general build.gradle to your individual sub-project build.gradle files?

Comment: I've edit the question answering a bit your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ant.replace to do this:

```
replaceTokens << {
    ant.replace(
        file:  "path/to/your/file",
        token: "stringtoreplace",
        value: config.purpose
    )
}

war.dependsOn replaceTokens
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a somewhat similar issue. I found it easier to keep separate environment (e.g. dev, qa, staging, prod etc.) specific properties/settings/config and then loaded/applied a specific one at suitable time in the build life-cycle. Following links were helpful:

1. https://blog.gradle.org/maven-pom-profiles
2. [Gradle : Copy different properties file depending on the environment and create jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771697/gradle-copy-different-properties-file-depending-on-the-environment-and-create)

PS: I'm responding to a bit older question, but hopefully these pointer may be of help to someone facing a similar issue.

Answer (score -2):

you can try something like this if only you need is to replace your placeholders

```
tasks.taskName.doFirst {
            exec {
                commandLine "perl", "-pi","-w","-e","s/${stringKey}/"+config.purpose+"/g" ,"filePath"
            }
        }
    }
```