# Building with different configs depending on the environment

Tags: java, gradle

I have two git repositories:

```
- myapp-public
- myapp-private
```

The second contains configuration information (some of which is sensitive hence a seperate private repository), which is built as a jar using gradle (config.jar). This jar is then supplied as an external dependancy when building the code in the public repository (resulting in myapp.jar), and used in the code as follows:

```
import com.myapp.property.Configuration;
Configuration.get(Configuration.NAME.KEYCLOAK_URL)
```

Depending on the environment to which the jar is to be deployed, I have to edit one or two properties in the Configuration class as follows, before building the config jar:

Local env:

```
props.setProperty(NAME.KEYCLOAK_URL.propertyName(), "http://localhost:8082/auth");
```

Production:

```
props.setProperty(NAME.KEYCLOAK_URL.propertyName(), "https://myapp.com/auth");
```

Having built the config jar, I then build my app as a fat jar and deploy to the relevant environment.

Using gradle, how might I better build my app for either local or prod environments?

Comment: I guess it might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771697/gradle-copy-different-properties-file-depending-on-the-environment-and-create

Comment: Have you worked it out?