# With Gradle, how do I switch a file contents when building based on an argument to build command?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

What I have is: a `db.properties file`, my program reads the information about my DB connection from this file.

What I want is: to have multiple files, like `db-dev.properties` and `db-staging.properties`, and when I build the app, I pass an argument to Gradle that forces it to use the contents of `db-X.properties` as a `db.properties` file. (Or maybe switch it based on an environment variable, if that's easier).

I don't use Spring or anything like that, I want to get this behaviour via just pure Gradle. Is there a reasonable way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle : Copy different properties file depending on the environment and create jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771697/gradle-copy-different-properties-file-depending-on-the-environment-and-create)

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, thanks!